# MySQL select most used IP's from user ID's

Tags: mysql, count

I have a list of login logs from our website, however I am needing to see which user ID has had the most IP's logged into it. Our table is as follows:

userid, ip, date (unix)

I need it to output which userid's have had the most IP's logged into them.

I've tried something such as:

```
SELECT 
    userID 
FROM loginLogs 
GROUP BY userID 
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT ip ) > 1
```

But that just shows a list of user ID's.

Comment: don't you ask to have only the first most logged user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select userID, count(distinct ip)
from loginLogs
Group by 1 
Order by 2 desc
```

Comment: "1" and "2" aren't columns that can be grouped or ordered?

Comment: @jjs9534. 1 and 2 refers to the order of the columns in the SELECT. The issue in this query is that it should be ORDER BY 2 DESC, otherwise this does the job

Comment: @jjs9534 In MySQL you can use numbers to refer to the order of the columns in your select statement saving time and typing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

```
SELECT `userID`, count(`ip`) cnt FROM `loginLogs` GROUP BY `userID` HAVING cnt > 1
```

Comment: This works however it shows the total amount of logins, not unique IP logins.

Answer (score 1):

You can just order by distinct values, descending;

```
SELECT userID, COUNT(DISTINCT ip) `distinct IP#s` 
FROM loginLogs 
GROUP BY userID 
ORDER BY `distinct IP#s` DESC;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8aea4/1).

Comment: This is the best answer. Asker should wait a few minutes before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to order those results `order by COUNT( DISTINCT  ip  ) desc` and take the first `Limit 0, 1`

```
SELECT `userID`
FROM `loginLogs`
GROUP BY `userID`
ORDER BY COUNT( DISTINCT `ip` ) desc
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userID, COUNT(*) AS count FROM loginLogs
GROUP BY userId ORDER BY count DESC
```

This will give you all of your users from most logged in to the least. Use LIMIT 1 if you want to limit the results.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap what you have in a subquery to get the list of userIDs and distinct IPs, as well.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ll.`userID`, ll.`ip`
FROM (  SELECT  `userID`, COUNT( 1 ) AS Cnt
        FROM    `loginLogs`
        GROUP BY `userID`
        HAVING  COUNT( DISTINCT `ip` ) > 1 ) id
LEFT JOIN `loginLogs` ll
    ON  id.`userID` = ll.`userID`
ORDER BY id.`Cnt`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see the user with the most ips and you also want to see the list of ips, you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html):

```
SELECT `userID`, group_concat(DISTINCT `ip`) 
FROM `loginLogs` 
GROUP BY `userID` 
ORDER BY COUNT( DISTINCT `ip` ) DESC
LIMIT 1
```